# Defining a macro for printing vectors with SplitList in xparse

Tags: matrices, xparse, vector

please look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\vv}{ s > { \SplitList { ; } } m }%
 {\begin{pmatrix}%
\ProcessList{#2}{\@vv}%
  \end{pmatrix}%
  \@firstitemtrue}

\newif\if@firstitem
\@firstitemtrue
\NewDocumentCommand{\@vv}{ m }%
 {\if@firstitem%
    \@firstitemfalse%
  \else%
 \\%
  \fi%
  #1}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

The vector is printend wrong:
\begin{equation}
  \vv{a;b;c;d;e;f;g}
\end{equation}

It should look like:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
 a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I tried to define a macro to typeset vectors comfortably. But something went wrong as you can see on the picture.

[image]

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: The `\vv` command is also used by the `\esvect` package, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\@firstitemfalse` command is done within a array cell, which is a group and will never be `false` outside, so use `\global\@firstitemfalse`, but a better solution is to use an `expl3` approach with `\seq at the end of this answer...

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\vv}{ s > { \SplitList { ; } } m }%
 {\begin{pmatrix}%
     \ProcessList{#2}{\@vv}%
  \end{pmatrix}%
  \@firstitemtrue}

\newif\if@firstitem
\@firstitemtrue
\NewDocumentCommand{\@vv}{ m }%
 {\if@firstitem%
    \global\@firstitemfalse%
  \else%
 \\%
  \fi%
  #1}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

The vector is printend wrong:
\begin{equation}
  \vv{a;b;c;d;e;f;g}
\end{equation}

It should look like:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
 a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Alternate solution with 'direct' usage of `expl3` features, so there's no need of `\if@firstitem` at all, since `\seq_use:Nn ... {\\}` cares for this.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \split_vector_list:n {%
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {#1}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\\}
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\vv}{ sm }{%
  \begin{pmatrix}%
     \split_vector_list:n {#2}
   \end{pmatrix}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The vector is printend wrong:
\begin{equation}
  \vv{a;b;c;d;e;f;g}
\end{equation}

It should look like:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
 a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the seq-use version (-1 for the global setting:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Desparate times require desperate measures ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I tried your first solution. I had to add \global also in the definition of the macro to make it work properly mor than once. :)

Comment: The second solution seems to be very clever but I don't know how to use the ExplSyntax. I tried to read the Manual but I did not help. Do you know another source to learn it?

Comment: @user125730: The `interface3` manual is rather a reference than a description how to use `expl3`. There is no clear introduction yet.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\vv}{ s > { \SplitList { ; } } m }%
 {\begin{pmatrix}%
\ProcessList{#2}{\@vv}%
  \end{pmatrix}%
  \@firstitemtrue}

\newif\if@firstitem
\@firstitemtrue
\NewDocumentCommand{\@vv}{ m }%
 {#1\\}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

The vector is printend wrong:
\begin{equation}
  \vv{a;b;c;d;e;f;g}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

each table cell is a local group so your boolean flag setting was being lost as soon as you did `\\`

Comment: Oh, I did not know that each table cell is a local group. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for a conditional: `pmatrix` is perfectly happy when the last row ends with `\\`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vv}{ s > { \SplitList { ; } } m }{%
  \begin{pmatrix}%
  \ProcessList{#2}{\innervv}%
  \end{pmatrix}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\innervv}{ m }{#1\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \vv{a;b;c;d;e;f;g}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
 a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the *-variant is meant for printing row vectors, then you have a small problem, so a different strategy is needed: first, split the argument at the first `;`, then apply `\SplitList` to the second part (if it exists). However this would require too many macros.

An approach based on `expl3` is therefore preferable:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vv}{ sm }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \vv_rowcol:nn { #2 } { & } }  % row vector
   { \vv_rowcol:nn { #2 } { \\ } } % column vector
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \vv_rowcol:nn
 {
  \begin{pmatrix}
  % split the input at semicolons
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vv_rowcol_seq { ; } { #1 }
  % deliver the items separated by & or \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l_vv_rowcol_seq { #2 }
  \end{pmatrix}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_vv_rowcol_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \vv{a;b;c;d;e;f;g}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
 a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \vv*{a;b;c;d;e;f;g}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]